# Maven profiles are not activating except default profile

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I am working on a spring-boot application. I have two profiles inside my POM, but when I am trying the build the project using clean install -Pdev its not reflecting the change in application.properties, it'll only reflect when I am using 'activeByDefault' tag in one of the profile.

```
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
        <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
    </properties>

</profile>
<profile>
    <id>release</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <activatedProperties>release</activatedProperties>
    </properties>
</profile>

</profiles>
```

If I am running clean install -Pdev I am getting this in my application.properties.
activatedProperties=@activatedProperties@

If I am setting the `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>` then I'll get the value inside application.properties.
activatedProperties=release.

The frustration is I am not able to use other profiles.

Comment: I think you need to add a space between the -P and the profile name.

Comment: @JJF it's the same thing with or without space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in your application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
```

If Maven doesn't find the directory which contains your application.properties file in runtime, you need to setup the Maven Resources Plugin to filter the directory.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

Or just add what profile you want to active in application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

***NOTE:*** The Maven profile and the Spring profile are different things.

Comment: Why do you think `<filtering>true</filtering>` staff is needed?

Comment: because that will allow you to insert properties defined in the <profile> tags into any file in the resources directory.

Comment: spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@ in application.properties will get injected without <filtering>true</filtering> staff .

Comment: Did you try it? I think that you want to say stuff instead of staff, right?

Comment: I did try it without resources tag. Yes, stuff, sorry.

Comment: It's OK, I'm going to update it, I'm not sure if current version of maven has activated that flag by default, I did this answer for a long time. So I'll update it, Thanks @theNoobProgrammer